# Extract zip file and keeping top folder using python

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have folder in like `CW1234.zip` and it has various folders and subfolders like below. So, `CW1234.zip` has `CW_All` folder which in turn has `CW123` and `CW234` folders and so on

```
CW1234.zip
  CW_All
    CW123
      xyz.pdf
    CW234
      abc.doc
```

and to extract I use this code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(r'CW41234.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
   # Extract all the contents of zip file in current directory
   zipObj.extract()
```

The only problem is the unzipped folder I get is from CW_All and all the subfolders and file.

What I want is to get it from CW1234 as one folder and then the structure follows?

**Current Output**

```
CW_All
   CW123
      xyz.pdf
   CW234
      abc.doc
```

**Expected Output**

```
CW1234
  CW_All
     CW123
        xyz.pdf
     CW234
        abc.doc
```

Couldn't find anything in the documentation also!!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`ZipFile.extract()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)? It has a `path` argument, which you should be able to work with.

Comment: the path argument is just if you want to store in specific location or the working directory!!

Comment: Could you update your question with what the expected outcome is? How it's written at the moment it isn't really clear what your end-goal is.

Comment: Done...please check now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ZipFile.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) we can simply provide a new path to extract the contents of the archive to, which we can base on the filename of the archive.

I have a .zip file with the following structure:

```
archive1024.zip:.
│
└───Folder_with_script
        stuff.py
```

Here is the script to extract all of the files inside of the archive into a sub-folder:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

file = "archive1024.zip"
with ZipFile(file, "r") as zFile:
    zFile.extractall(path=file.split(".")[0])
```

I now have a folder-structure like this:

```
J:.
│   archive1024.zip
│   unzip.py
│
└───archive1024
    └───Folder_with_script
            stuff.py
```

Comment: How I can encounter the error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long: 'archive1024\\Folder_with_script'`?

Comment: @pRo I'm not really sure, because you've not given that much info. Maybe you're trying to create a filename that is too long? Windows has a really low threshold for how long their names can be (sometimes including the path to the file). However, I think whatever problem you're having would be best answered in a new question instead of the comments of this one.