# ZipFile.extractall Does not Copy Subdirectories, instead renames files with path

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I am currently trying to write a script that will extract a zip file created in powershell with `Create-Archive` to a destination. Here is how I am currently doing it:

```
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(destination_path)
```

This works for the most part, but there is a folder in the zip file. Instead of copying the folder and the files within that folder, it copies the files to the given `destination_path` and renames them. For example, I have a file called "BatteryDead.html" in a folder called "templates". When extracting it, it places a file named `templates\BatteryDead.html` into the root folder.

Is there a way I can have it extract the sub folder (and that folder's subfolders) as is? With keeping the directories in tact?

It should be noted, opening the ZIP file without extracting shows the correct directories and file names.

Here's the file structure before extraction:

```
./zipped_directory.zip
|
|
|-----templates/
          |
          |-----'BatteryDead.html'
|-----'testfile.txt'
```

After using `extractall()`:

```
/root/
|
|
|-----'templates\BatteryDead.html'
|-----'testfile.txt'
```

This is python version 3.7.3

Comment: This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480440/zip-folder-with-subfolder-in-python) uses `os.walk()` maybe this could help you or point you in the right direction

Comment: @KevinHernandez thanks for the response! That answer seems to be referring to Zipping up a directory unstead of unzipping. I'll keep looking in that direction though.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your description of what you want to do sounds like the way `ZipFile.extractall()` already behaves. Can you check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63077068/8805293) and see if it's a similar problem? If not, could you please create a mock-up with the folder-structure before and after the extraction?

Comment: @HampusLarsson Added the file structures based on the syntax you used in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tmello225 I don't think you can actually have a forward-slash inside of a file-name. Are you sure that it isn't really creating a folder? If you change your directory inside of `/root/` and launch the command `tree` is the output of the file on the same line or in separate lines?

Comment: @HampusLarsson sorry, my bad. It's actually a backslash. I'll change the question

Comment: @HampusLarsson Also this is on a linux system so `tree` isn't available, but `ls` shows it as the name of the file.

Comment: @Tmello225 When creating a zipfile, one of the standards are that the paths should be normalized with forward-slashes. What is the source of the zipfile? If it's producible by code, can you share that code?

Comment: @HampusLarsson I wonder, could it be caused by the zip file being created on a windows system and unzipped on linux?

Comment: @Tmello225 The only reason it could happen as far as I know is if it's created in Windows, where both back-slashes and forward-slashes are used as directory-separators. However, as I said, the specification for how to create zip-files state that back-slashes should be normalized to forward-slashes. That's why I asked what the source of the file was, or if you had a programatical way of creating the file.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Ah sorry I missed that. It is created using the powershell Compress-Archive command.

Comment: @Tmello225 And there is your problem. See [this github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2140).

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you! I'll add the bit about the powershell to the question, if you want to submit this as the answer I'll accept.